# Toggle Class for individual elements in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a todo list that is generated via jsonplaceholder , the button on click populates the div with dummy content.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on an individual div(task) it should be removed/hidden.

So far,

```
<button id="btn" v-on:click= 'getTodo'>Show Todo</button>
    <div id="jsonData" v-for = 'todo in todos' >
        <ul v-bind:class = '{active: isActive}' v-on:click = 'removeTask'>
            <li>{{todo.title}} </li>
            <li id="status"> Task Status : {{todo.completed}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS

```
var vm =  new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        todos: [],
        isActive: false
    }
},
methods: {
    getTodo: function() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then((response) => {
            this.todos = response.data;
        })
    },
    removeTask: function() {
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
}

})
```

The 'removeTask' event handler toggles the classes for all the generated divs(tasks) and not to the clicked div.

How do I add/remove the class on the clicked div?

Comment: are you trying to set the `isActive` prop on the individual todo?

Comment: Yeah , that’s what I’m trying to achieve

Comment: You are setting the overall prop of `isActive` to true/false which doesn't make sense when you want to manipulate the individual todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `axios` API i get the todos and pragmatically loop over the individual todos and apply an `isActive` prop to all of them. 
These props can now be toggled via `toggleTodo` when passing the todo' `id` to the method. :-)

Notice i have applied a `v-if="todo.isActive"` upon the `ul` this can also be translated to `:class="{active: todo.isActive}"` if you were wanting to apply some styling i.e for transitions etc.

By using this approach you can use the same logic to create methods such as `completeTodo` and `removeTodo` etc

I have added a `showList` prop in order to show/hide the actual full list.

I noticed you are using `v-bind` and `v-on` - this is absolutely valid but VUE ^2.0 can handle [shorthand binding](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands) :-)

I also noticed you are using `single` quotes for your HTML attributes... Although this does not break your markup i think it's best practice to keep them as `double quotes`.

```js
var vm =  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [],
    showList: false
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getTodos()
  },
  methods: {
    getTodos () {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .then(res => {
        res.data = res.data.map(todo => {
          todo.isActive = false
          return todo
        })

        this.todos = res.data
      })
    },
    showTodos () { this.showList = !this.showList },
    toggleTodo (id) {
      this.todos = this.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.isActive = !todo.isActive
        }
        return todo
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <button @click="showTodos()">{{this.showList ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Todos</button>
  <div v-if="todos.length && showList" v-for="todo in todos">
    <button id="btn" @click="toggleTodo(todo.id)">Toggle Todo</button>

    <ul v-if="todo.isActive" :class="{active: todo.isActive}">
      <li>{{todo.title}} </li>
      <li id="status"> Task Status : {{todo.completed}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style lang="css">
  .active {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for the late reply. The reason that i'm not using shorthands is because I have just started exploring this framework and trying not to use any shortcuts and thanks for helping me out and advise :).

Answer (score 1):

`isActive` is one for the entire instance, not every individual todo.

What you'll need to do is to to populate the todo list either by mapping the response data or simply use the response data's `completed` property.

```
{
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 193,
    "title": "rerum debitis voluptatem qui eveniet tempora distinctio a",
    "completed": true
}
```

Every item of the response's todo has the `completed` prop, so you can use that.

That's how you'd go about doing it:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      todos: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTodo: function() {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then((response) => {
          this.todos = response.data;
        })
    },
    toggleCompleted: function(todo) {
      todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button id="btn" v-on:click='getTodo'>Show Todo</button>
  <div id="jsonData" v-for='todo in todos'>
    <ul v-bind:class='{active: todo.completed}' v-on:click='toggleCompleted(todo)'>
      <li>{{todo.title}} </li>
      <li id="status"> Task Status : {{todo.completed ? 'Completed' : 'Active'}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```